# numpy for no repeating for two columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Basically, I am looking to solve without repeating comparing via AA and BB. If AA has 1, BB will start with 1, rather than repeating.

```
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
  'A': np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0], dtype='int32'),
  'B': np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,  0, 1], dtype='int32')
  })



df2['AA'] = np.where( (df2['A'] > df2['A'].shift(1)),1,0)
df2['BB'] = np.where(( (df2['B'] > df2['B'].shift(1))),1,0)
```

I am getting repeating of BB. How can I get without repeating 1 if AA has 1, next BB should get 1 rather than repeating.

```
df2
Out[24]: 
    A  B  AA  BB
0   1  0   0   0
1   1  0   0   0
2   0  0   0   0
3   1  0   1   0
4   0  1   0   1
5   1  0   1   0
6   1  0   0   0
7   0  1   0   1
8   0  1   0   0
9   0  0   0   0
10  0  0   0   0
11  0  0   0   0
12  0  1   0   1
```

The result should be as following.
if AA has 1 in previous row or past rows, and BB will start with 1 rather than repeating 1 at AA again, likewise in BB it should not repeat.

```
Out[24]: 
    A  B  AA  BB
0   1  0   0   0
1   1  0   0   0
2   0  0   0   0
3   1  0   1   0
4   0  1   0   1
5   1  0   1   0
6   1  0   0   0
7   0  1   0   1
8   0  1   0   0
9   0  0   0   0
10  0  0   0   0
11  0  0   0   0
12  0  1   0   0
```

Comment: Could you show us what output you would like so we can help?  I don't really understand what you are asking us to do.

Comment: Agreed with @PaulBrennan. Please explain it better and show us a desired output.

Comment: @PaulBrennan I add more detail now.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva I just add more details which will have not repeating compared to two columns.

Comment: The logic you are looking for is still unclear. The only difference I see is the `0` in `df2.loc[12, 'BB']` -- but why? Could you try to explain again?